# Monitor resolution wont change

Tags: ati, resolution, monitor

I recently upgraded to ubuntu 10.10 , and installed the proprietary drivers for the ATI video card.Now when i go to change monitor from Mirror to individual or change the resolution it asks for me to log out and log back in , now when i do that it just reverts back to the same resolution and same mirrored preference which i don't want.Is there a way i can change it and keep it changed?

Comment: i know how to change it ,but for some reason when i do go there and do change it and log out and back in it will revert back to its original settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your monitor settings by going to System-> Preferences-> Monitors and you should see available settings like this.

[image: Monitor Preferences]

Once you change any of the settings and hit Apply your settings will take effect without logging out.

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously a bit old, but if you are still looking for a solution try...

1. Open up a terminal (ctrl+alt+t)
2. Go to your config folder (cd ~/.config)
3. Open up your file for editing (gedit monitors.xml)
4. Your resolution will be listed here as `<width>` and `<height>`
5. Change them to `<width>1920</width>` and `<height>1080</height>` - obviously if your resolution is 1980x1080! if not change them appropriately.

There is a more detailed description here... [Ubuntu 11.10 dual monitor set up instructions](http://www.sudo-juice.com/ubuntu-11-10-dual-monitors-set-up-not-saving/)

Answer (score 0):

did you execute `sudo aticonfig --initial` after the installation process? Otherwise `xrandr` can be the source of your problems.

edit: i forgot to post this link that can be really useful for anyone using the proprietary ATI driver http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Main_Page